# windows won't expell USB flash drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive

Sometimes, even if I closed all the opened files, I can't remove my usb flash drive because Windows (both 7 and 8.1) complains that it is used by "another program", but never bothers to tell which one!

Comment: So you are physically prevented from pulling It out?

Comment: Since a flash drive is a solid state memory device, it might be that the OS is waiting to see if there will be another change before it commits to writing the changed directory information. All you would need to do is wait about a minute and then try again.

Comment: @Eejin I think he's prevented from removing it according to the safely remove hardware thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). This tool is able to tell you which process are using your device. Once loaded up:

1. Press **Find** (Find Handle or DLL...)
2. Enter the drive letter of your USB device e.g E:/
3. A list of process that are using the device will be displayed which you will then be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks it worked. It turned out it was recorningmanager.exe a program of realplayer.